# How to scan join query results into a struct containing a slice of structs using sqlx

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, join, sqlx

Here are the tables that are relevant to this question:

lists:

```
                      Table "public.lists"
   Column    |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |      Default      
-------------+--------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 id          | uuid   |           | not null | gen_random_uuid()
 user_id     | uuid   |           | not null | 
 list_name   | text   |           | not null | 
 description | text   |           | not null | 
 created_at  | bigint |           | not null | 
 updated_at  | bigint |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "lists_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
Referenced by:
    TABLE "todos" CONSTRAINT "fk_list_id" FOREIGN KEY (list_id) REFERENCES lists(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

and todos:

```
                      Table "public.todos"
   Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |      Default      
------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------------
 id         | uuid    |           | not null | gen_random_uuid()
 list_id    | uuid    |           | not null | 
 user_id    | uuid    |           | not null | 
 content    | text    |           | not null | 
 done       | boolean |           | not null | false
 created_at | bigint  |           | not null | 
 updated_at | bigint  |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "todos_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "todos_content_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (content)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_list_id" FOREIGN KEY (list_id) REFERENCES lists(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    "fk_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

and these are the structs that I would ideally like to use:

```golang
type Todo struct {
    ID        string `db:"id"`
    ListID    string `db:"list_id"`
    UserID    string `db:"user_id"`
    Content   string `db:"content"`
    Done      bool   `db:"done"`
    CreatedAt int64  `db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt int64  `db:"updated_at"`
}

type ListWithTodos struct {
    ID          string `db:"id"`
    UserID      string `db:"user_id"`
    ListName    string `db:"list_name"`
    Description string `db:"description"`
    Todos       []Todo
    CreatedAt   int64  `db:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   int64  `db:"updated_at"`
}
```

What I would like to do is select a list and add all of its children todos (todos with a list_id equal to the list's id) to the field `ListWithTodos.Todos`. I currently have this query which returns all of the todos with the parent list attached (and I know this won't work with the struct I have):

```sql
SELECT l.*, t.* FROM lists l RIGHT JOIN todos t ON l.id=t.list_id WHERE l.id='insert uuid here';
```

and my go code and structs obviously don't work with the query.
What query would I use to get the results into a single struct and what sqlx functions would I use to do this?

Comment: The WHERE clause condition makes the RIGHT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move it to the ON clause to get true RIGHT JOIN result.

Comment: However, most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change the results at all, it is still the 3 children todos (and all of them have the parent list attached)

Comment: Perhaps you don't need an outer join?

Comment: @jarlh I'm sorry I don't understand?